# Add as Facebook friend on click iPhone

Tags: xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook

In my app I need to implement **+add as friend** type button to send Facebook friend requests. And if the user is not logged in then the login dialog should appear. I searched in Google and also in Stack Overflow and one or two questions for iOS add as friend button but with no answer, so I could not get anything working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as having a link like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?id=FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID&app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID&redirect_uri=SOME_URL"> ADD AS FRIEND </a>
```

So the URL to use is:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?id=FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID&app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID&redirect_uri=SOME_URL
```

And you have to replace `FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID`, `FACEBOOK_APP_ID`, and `SOME_URL` by the real values.

On the iPhone, I would open a UIWebView pointing to this URL.

Comment: very much thanx for reply but i need little help i tried this api in web view for iphone but on click of link it comes with error code 100,invalid parameter to api. I think this error is becoz parameters are wrong. I have app_id, api_key and secret for facebook connect. I gave link of facebook friend as FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID and SOME_URL.For FACEBOOK_APP_ID i gave my app_id.what to give in FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID and in SOME_URL?

Comment: FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID is the facebook id of the user you want to like. SOME_URL is an URL where the user will be redirected after he added the friend. What I did for SOME_URL , is that I put a web page at some adress on the web, and this webpage executes some javascript to close the window (you could intercept that javascript in your UIWebViewDelegate and close your UIWebView for example)